# Refusing your app's TextStyle in a Glance widget

Tags: glance-appwidget

In a glance `Text()`, there's a `style` attribute, and this takes a glance `TextStyle`.

This `TextStyle` is different to the `TextStyle` you use in your `MaterialTheme`. So you can't reuse your app's `TextStyles`.

Is it possible to reuse your app's `TextStyles` in a glance app widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `MaterialTheme` is designed for Jetpack Compose UI elements not for Glance. Given the limitations of AppWidgets (i.e no custom fonts) I would avoid reusing the theme.

We are working on a "theming" API for Glance, in the meantime you can keep the TextStyle as top-level variable and reuse it when needed.

Comment: I can't reuse the TextStyles from JC UI though, correct?

Comment: The class must be the one in the glance package but You could potentially reuse the values of your TextStyle to fill it. But as said it's limited to certain values only

Comment: Why even TextStyle(color) not working on Glance?

Comment: because you need to use the TextStyle class in the Glance package